# caroufredsel reloads a page

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

before i made some modifications to css! everything was fine but now "carouFredSel" functions constantly reloads a page ( strange behaviour )
the url of demo page is http://demos.illucent.info/butts/index.html
i think this is somewhere at the bottom of the script but i do not which one exactly

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#carousel1').carouFredSel({
             align:"left",
             width: '100%',
             prev: '#prev1',
             next: '#next1',
             items  : {
             visible  : 13,
             width  : "100%"
            },
             scroll : {
              items   : 2,
              duration  : 1500,
              pauseDuration : 3500
             }

            });
            $('#carousel2').carouFredSel({
             align:"left",
             width: '100%',
             prev: '#prev2',
             next: '#next2',
             items  : {
             visible  : 13,
             width  : "100%"
            },
             scroll : {
              items   : 2,
              duration  : 1500,
              pauseDuration : 3500
             }
            });
            $('#carousel3').carouFredSel({
             align:"left",
             width: '100%',
             prev: '#prev3',
             next: '#next3',
             items  : {
             visible  : 13,
             width  : "100%"
            },
             scroll : {
              items   : 2,
              duration  : 1500,
              pauseDuration : 3500
             }
            });
           //margins
           $(".carousel img").css({"margin":"0px 0px 0px 5px"});
           var items = $('.list_switch li a').each(function () {
           $(this).click(function () {
             //remove previous class and add it to clicked tab
             items.removeClass('current');
             $(this).addClass('current');
            });
             });
             //hide all content divs and show current one
             $('.wrapper').hide().eq(items.index($(this))).show('fast');

             // resume the slide on the selected slider
             $('.carousel').eq(items.index($(this))).trigger("play");
             $('.carousel').eq(items.index($(this))).trigger("slideTo");

           // select the first tab on page load       
           items[0].click();

           });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's because of a change to the CSS.

in the $(document).ready function your are invoking the click event of the the first item in your collection called 'items'.

```
items[0].click();
```

the first element in your items collection is this hyperlink:

```
<a href="index.html">
```

which redirects to the same page. When the page has reloaded, the $(document).ready obviously runs again doing the same thing.

try commenting out

```
   items[0].click();
```

and you should find that it stops happening.